# How to do something when I change a field in Django admin for a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have currently a boolean field called `is_active` on a model. Whenever I set this field manually in the Django admin to `True` (initially it it's false) I want it to do a certain action.
How can I trigger this field in Django to do this certain action when it is set to `True`?

I heard about a `save_model()` method but i don't know how it works.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can indeed override the [**`save_model(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) in the `ModelAdmin`. The `form` parameter contains the `Form` in the model admin, and you can inspect the [**`.changed_data`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.changed_data) to inspect if the value changed:

```
from app.models import Company
from django.contrib import admin

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        field = 'is_active'
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if change and field in form.changed_data and form.cleaned_data.get(field):
            # ... do a certain action
            pass

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i got this error when i tried this : save_model() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Comment: @Reda: sorry, I made a typo: the `self` is already passed implicitly. So in the `super().save_model(...)` call, the `self, ` should be removed.